# Questions about Hatcher 3.2.16

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher's exercise 3.2.16 states

> Show that if X and Y are finite CW complexes such that $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ contain no elements of order a power of a given prime p, then the same is true for $X \times Y$.

Now the hint says to use the Künneth Formula

> $H^*(X;R)\otimes_R H^*(Y;R) \cong H^*(X \times Y ;R)$ when X,Y are CW complexes and $H^k(Y;R)$ is a finitely generated free R module.

for various fields R.

Here's what I need help with (my attempts are also included):

1. Firstly, I'm looking for a clarification about the question. I know the following logic is flawed but I can't figure out why:
   Since X is a finite CW complex, $H^k(X,R) = 0$ for all $k \geq m$ for some number $m$ since there are only finitely many cells. So for $\alpha$ in $H^1(X)$, we have that $\alpha^m \in H^m(X;R) = 0$ (product given by the cup product $\alpha \smile \alpha)$. So pick $n$ such that $p^n > m$, then $\alpha^{p^n} = 0$ and $H^*(X)$ has an element of order $p^n$ always. I'm aware that I'm probably missing something basic.
2. Assuming the question is well posed and that 1) is not an issue, then my first thought was to use the formula not for a field but with $R = \mathbb{Z}$. If $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ have no elements of order $p^n$ for any n, then my first guess is that they are torsion free. If they are indeed torsion free, then by the Universal Coefficient Theorem, we have that $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^r$ and $H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^l$ so $H^*(X\times Y;\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{rl}$ which is torsion free. But I haven't been able to show why $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z})$ would need to be torsion free. If this is correct, then I'm looking to see why that is the case, and if not, then a counterexample.
3. Assuming I was wrong and the approach  in 2) was incorrect, I tried thinking about Hatcher's hint more carefully and then decided to look at $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ as a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ module. I couldn't get very far but the hope was to extend $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. My guess being that the latter is a free $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ module and by the Künneth formula, $H^*(X \times Y;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, which is an extension of $H^*(X \times Y;\mathbb{Z})$ and was hoping to construct an order $p^n$ element here towards a contradiction. No luck so far, but any advice would be great.
4. I also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154632/hatcher-exercise-3-2-16) MSE post which I didn't find too helpful. The comments seem to suggest studying the order of elements or use Lagranges Theorem in the tensor product but wouldn't we expect the tensor to be free over $\mathbb{Z}$ and have elements of infinite order and Lagranges theorem only applies to finite groups?

Comment: RE 1, in this context "order" means not order under multiplication (cup product), but rather addition - elements of order $p^n$ are those satisfying $p^n\alpha=0$ (and have nonzero smaller multiplies)

Comment: Ah okay. It was indeed something basic I was missing. Thanks! I might be missing something but does that mean anything for the second question a priori?

Comment: Try combining with the universal coefficient theorem, and use both rational and mod $p$ coefficients. Try dimension counting for the various vector spaces that arise. (There is no reason for the integral cohomology groups to be torsion-free.)

Comment: So I tried that out.So far:the cohomology $H^n(X,\mathbb{Q}) \cong Hom_\mathbb{Q}(H_n(X),\mathbb{Q})$. This is just the dual of $H_n(X)$ viewed as a Q vector space. We have the analogous statements for Y, and Z/p coefficients. Now if since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, the cohomology group of Y is free, we can use the theorem stated on the post. So dim $H^n(X)$ dim $H^n(Y) = $ dim $H^n(X\times Y)$ with coefficients in rationals and in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. But where do we go from here? What does the assumption of the order of an elements in cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients relate here?

Comment: Though the dimension statements only hold if the dimensions are finite - I should note

Comment: These are finite CW complexes, so their (co)homology groups are finitely generated. So they are direct sums of $\mathbb{Z}$ and cyclic groups of prime power order. How do each of those summands contribute to rational or mod $p$ cohomology?

Comment: Wouldn't the cohomology groups be finitely generated as Z, Q, Z/pZ coefficients respectively? So they'd be direct sums of Z and cyclic groups of prime power order when we look at $H^n(X, Q)$ will be direct summands of $Q$ and some other torsion groups? If that's not the case then I would imagine that the free part of the summands would be isomorphic to the rational cohomology and the torsion part should be isomorphic to mod p cohomology - would be my guess. Though I don't immediately see why. If that were the case, then the torsion components wouldn't have a Z/p^n term for any n, but ....

Comment: .... but could possibly have other torsion, terms I'd imagine.

Comment: As I said, use the universal coefficient theorem to relate integral homology to rational and mod p cohomology.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to do that with the cohomology UCT. What's confusing me about that is that if I consider the cw chain with coefficients in, say, $Q$, then the UCT states $H^n(X,Q) \cong Hom_Q(H_n(X;Q),Q)$, since $H_k(X,Q)$ is a free Q-module. But I don't see how this connects to $H^n(X,Z)$ or $H^n(X,Z/p)$. If I consider cw chains with Z-coefficients and cohomologies into Q, then we get the usual $Ext, H^n, Hom$ chain by UCT, but I don't know how to check whether $H_n(X,Z)$ behaves as a Q-module. (And respectively for Z/p). Am I missing an observation here or mis-applying the UCT?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri why we need to relate the integral cohomology to both the rational and the mod p cohomology?

Comment: I don't know if we *need* to, but my approach involved dimension-counting. The dimension of $H^n(X;\mathbb{Q})$ as a rational vector space will always equal the rank of the free part of the integral homology, and then you can compare that to the vector space dimension of $H^n(X;\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is a finite CW complex, then its rational homology $H^n(X; \mathbb{Q})$ is a rational vector space. By the Universal Coefficient Theorem (Theorem 3.2 in Hatcher, applied with $G=\mathbb{Q}$), its dimension is the rank of $H_n(X)$ as a free abelian group: the finite summands of $H_n(X)$ do not contribute (since there are no maps from a finite group into $\mathbb{Q}$), and nothing from $H_{n-1}(X)$ contributes (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective as an abelian group, or you can use the properties of Ext that Hatcher gives just after the theorem to see that the Ext group is zero when $G=\mathbb{Q}$).

If $p$ is a prime, the only way for $H^n(X)$ to have elements of order a power of $p$ is for $H_n(X)$ or $H_{n-1}(X)$ to also have elements of order a power of $p$, this time by the Universal Coefficient Theorem with $G=\mathbb{Z}$. So if $H^*(X)$ has no elements of order $p^m$ for any $m$, then the same is true for $H_*(X)$. In this case, $H^n(X; \mathbb{F}_p)$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space with dimension again equal to the rank of $H_n(X)$ as a free abelian group: any summands of order prime to $p$ in $H_n(X)$ or $H_{n-1}(X)$ will not contribute to $H^n(X; \mathbb{F}_p)$ by the Universal Coefficient Theorem (with $G=\mathbb{Z}/p$).

Now by the above and the Künneth theorem with various coefficients, the dimension of $H^n(X \times Y; \mathbb{F}_p)$ is equal to
\begin{align}
\dim H^n(X \times Y; \mathbb{F}_p) &= 
\sum_{i=0}^n \dim H^i(X; \mathbb{F}_p) \dim H^{n-i}(Y; \mathbb{F}_p) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n rk H_i(X) rk H_{n-i}(Y) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \dim H^i(X;\mathbb{Q}) \dim H^{n-i}(Y; \mathbb{Q}) \\
&= \dim H^n(X \times Y; \mathbb{Q}) \\
&= rk H_n(X \times Y).
\end{align}
On the other hand, if $H^*(X \times Y)$ contained an element of order $p^m$ for some $m$, then the same is true for $H_*(X \times Y)$, and so the dimension of $H^n(X \times Y; \mathbb{F}_p)$ will not equal the rank of $H_n(X \times Y)$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type this. A couple of silly questions: 1) Are all the homologies here assumed to be with the usual $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients? 2) the last statement says "and so the dimension of (×;) will not equal the rank of (×) for some ". Is that because whichever $H^n$ contains that element of order $p^m$ will have an extra torsion thus reducing the dimension but not the rank since the rank comes from $H_n(X),H_n(Y)$? 3) Wouldn't $dim(H^n(X;F_p)) = rk(H_n(X))$ as a free $F_p$ module and not as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module?

Comment: (1) unless otherwise indicated, yes. (2) It's the universal coefficient theorem again: $p^m$-torsion in $H^n$ has to come from $p^m$-torsion in $H_n$, which will lead to extra copies of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in mod $p$ cohomology. (3) The assertion is that the dimension of $H^n(X, \mathbb{F}_p)$ as an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space is equal to the rank of $H_n(X)$ as an abelian group (i.e., the number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Okay, I think that mostly makes sense. I guess the last bit that doesn't make sense is that why does $p^m$ torsion on $H^n$ come from $p^m$ torsion in $H_n$ and not $H_{n-1}$. I thought torsion is captured by $Ext(H_{n-1})$ by the UCT and that cohomologies shift torsion up by 1 dimension?

Comment: Yes, you're right about that.

Comment: I  did not get the idea of the second paragraph in the solution

Comment: @Secretly The point is "$H_*(Z)$ contains no elements of order $p$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $H^*(Z)$ contains no elements of order $p$" and then in this case, $H^n(Z)$ is free abelian and $H^n(Z; \mathbb{F}_p)$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of dimension equal to the rank of $H^n(Z)$.

Comment: is there a proof for the first statement? ..... How the rest of the comment will help us in the solution?

Comment: Do you mean the first statement in my comment, the "if and only if" statement? That's the first sentence in paragraph 2: use the Universal Coefficient Theorem.

Comment: I see your point thank you :)

Comment: what about the prove for primes different than $p$?

Comment: why studying for $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F_p$ suffices? How about other fields?

Comment: How what you proved show that $X \times Y$ contains no elements of order a power of the given prime?

Comment: "why studying for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ suffices?" I don't see a gap in my proof, so why introduce any other fields? "what about the prove for primes different than $p$"? What is there to prove for other primes? The statement refers to a given prime $p$; the other primes are not relevant. "How what you proved show that $X \times Y$ contains no elements of order a power of the given prime? That's the whole point of the problem. Maybe create a new question addressing this and all of your remaining issues.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808437/more-questions-about-hatcher-3-2-16 here is my question if you could possibly answer my previous comment here there I would appreciate this.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between rank and dimension?

Comment: what do you mean by "of order prime to p" in the line before last in your second paragraph of the solution? Can you please explain in your answer to my above question?

Comment: I am not able to provide the level of answers you need: sentence by sentence, word by word.