# A question about 3.2.16 in Allen Hatcher.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite $CW$ complexes such that $H^*(X;\mathbb Z)$ and $H^*(Y;\mathbb Z)$ contain no elements of order a power of a given prime $p,$ then the same is true for $X \times Y.$

Here is a part of a solution I found online:

> [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Why in the last line he is substituting for the homology groups by the same values of the cohomology groups, could someone clarify this to me please?

**Exit:**

I also did not get the idea of the second paragraph in the solution here [Questions about Hatcher 3.2.16](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057105/questions-about-hatcher-3-2-16?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I think they are speaking on the same thing, Could someone clarify this to me please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi9QX.png

Comment: That's one question. The second question is why the author claims that $H^∗$
 are torsion free? This is false for example for real projective space and $p=3$. Isn't $p$ fixed here? And the third question is: what exactly the author is trying to show with the sequence of isomorphism? He already claimed $H^*$ are free? I don't get what is happening here.

Comment: @freakish I did not get what you said? The goal is to show that the product contains no elements of order a power of a given prime.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm referring to this partial online solution. Which seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "solution" is simply inaccurate. Take $X$ to be the CW-complex obtained by attaching a $2$-cell to $S^1$ along a degree $n$ map $S^1\rightarrow S^1$. Then, $H^{\ast}(X)=\mathbb{Z}[a]/(na,a^2)$ with $|a|=2$. For $n\neq0$, this cohomology clearly contains torsion, hence is neither torsion-free nor free. Yet, choosing $n$ coprime to $p$ guarantees the cohomology contains no elements of order a $p$-power. Thus, the claim at the bottom of p.68 in your screenshot is irredeemably wrong. I suggest following Hatcher's hint or finding some other way of applying the Künneth theorem (which the chapter was about) to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please include an answer to my edit in your solution if you do not mind?

Comment: but the problem has an extra assumption of not having an element of order a power of a prime.

Comment: @Secretly no, you misunderstand Hatcher's exercise. The prime $p$ is fixed and the assumption is that neither of cohomologies has element of order $p^n$. But they can have elements of order $q$ for some other prime $q$. Meaning those cohomologies don't have to be torsion free. That's why the proposed solution is wrong. However Hatcher  does give a correct hint: use Kunneth formula.