# More questions about hatcher 3.2.16.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am trying to understand the solution given for the following problem here on this site:

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite $CW$ complexes such that $H^*(X;\mathbb Z)$ and $H^*(Y;\mathbb Z)$ contain no elements of order a power of a given prime $p,$ then the same is true for $X \times Y.$

Here is the link to the solution given here:

[Questions about Hatcher 3.2.16](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057105/questions-about-hatcher-3-2-16)

Here are the two parts of the solution I do not understand:

1- If $p$ is a prime, the only way for $H^n(X)$ to have elements of order a power of $p$ is for $H_n(X)$ to also have elements of order a power of $p$, this time by the Universal Coefficient Theorem with $G=\mathbb{Z}$

**My questions about this part is as follows:**

Why is this statement true and how are we using this idea in the solution?

**My questions about the comments is as follows:**

Also, in the third comment, the advice was to calculate the **integral** cohomology groups? Why we are calculating those groups?

How can we implement the following advice given in the comments by John Palmieri "use the universal coefficient theorem to relate integral homology to rational and mod p cohomology"?

And finally, what are the correct logical sequence of steps for solving this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For point 1 you can find calculation here (Corollaries) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Corollaries The linked question of course presents it incorrectly. Torsion of $H^i$ is equal to torsion of $H_{i-1}$. And therefore the assumption that $H^*$ doesn't have elements of order $p$ is equivalent to $H_*$ not having such element (note: $*$, not for fixed $n$).

Comment: can you elaborate more please? What are the most logical sequence of steps for the solution?

Comment: @freakish what is the point of calculating the rational cohomology?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. Can't we just apply Kunneth formula for $R=\mathbb{Z}$? Then the conclusion is simple, right? Both cohomologies don't have element of order $p$, and so neither does their tensor product and/or direct product. But Hatcher also gives the hint "Apply Theorem 3.15 (Kunneth formula) with coefficients in various fields". Why fields? What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, I know why you can't simply use $R=\mathbb{Z}$. That's because the Kunneth formula requires $H^k(Y;R)$ to be finitely generated **free** $R$-module. I missed the "free" part. And here those cohomologies need not be free. And that's why chosing fields instead is useful - because over a field everything is free, and so we can apply Kunneth formula. But then we have to deduce something about $R=\mathbb{Z}$ from formulas for fields. Which sounds like a job for UCT.

Comment: How what was proved in the link I mentioned show that $X \times Y$ contains no elements of order a power of the given prime p?@freakish